# Check if movieclip is inside another movieclip [AS3]

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I need help creating a function that will check if a movieclip is inside another movieclip in actionscript 3.0. I created a movieclip called MyImage, which is dragged around by the user on top of another movieclip called BannerStage. When the user stops dragging MyImage, the function should return true or false, true if MyImage is inside of BannerStage and false if all corners of MyImage are outside of BannerStage.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

My Solution:

```
var inter = firstClip.getRect(this).intersection(secondClip.getRect(this));
if ((inter.width*inter.height) == 0) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this if you want to test if all corners of one are in all corners of the other:

```
banner.getRect().containsRect(draggable.getRect());

// or the reverse

draggable.getRect().containsRect(banner.getRect());
```

This works if they're in the same coordinate space.

If all you care about is *any* part of one overlapping *any* part of another (but you don't care if one contains the other completely) then a simple hitTestObject works.

```
draggable.hitTestObject(banner);
// or
banner.hitTestObject(draggable);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply your code works but the problem is that it returns false when one corner is out of the rectangle. What I need it to do is return false when **all** four corners are out of the rectangle

Comment: ok i ended up using the intersection method to find the height and width of the interestion between the two movieclips. I'll edit the question with the solution

Comment: Excellent!  I don't normally compare rects with the rectangle functions.  Glad to see that one of them worked out!